# Username not getting displayed in TM1 Web when using CAM

Tags: cognos, cognos-tm1

We have developed a TM1 application which is accessible through tm1 web, and using Cognos Integrated securty,
If we login to Cognos environment first and then to tm1, then it gets the username on tm1 web screen, next to the label Welcome: Juneja, Ruchika (like this)
Otherwise if we login to TM1 directly, it just shows an empty Welcome:
Has anyone faced the similar issue before.
Any help to resolve this issue is welcome. 
Thanks!

Comment: Is anonymous access turned off?

Comment: yes I checked the settings on Cognos content management server, Allow anonymous access is False.

Answer (score 0):

Check `}ClientGroups` cube. if the cube doesn't provide enough details check `}client` dimension's attributes. There is a way to match CAMID with the username.